# SAXParser gives FileNotFoundException for XML file

Tags: java, xml, filenotfoundexception, saxparser

My Java application gives a FileNotFoundException when trying to parse
an XML file with the SAXParser class. The stack trace is:

```
    java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method),
    java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source), 
    java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source), 
    java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source), 
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown  Source), 
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source),  
    java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown  Source), 
    java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown   Source), 
    java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown  Source), 
    java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown   Source), 
    java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source),  
    java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source),  
    java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source), 
    java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source),  
    java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
```

I ran the application on Windows and on Linux, on Linux I can reproduce it more
frequently (I don't know why...). The problem appears to occur randomly and I am sure the file exists and can be read.

- JRE release details:

```
    IMPLEMENTOR="Eclipse Adoptium"
    IMPLEMENTOR_VERSION="Temurin-17.0.2+8"
    JAVA_VERSION="17.0.2"
    JAVA_VERSION_DATE="2022-01-18"
```

- I checked and removed any redundant SAXParser classes from the classpath.
- I tried different folders as the file source folder (local, samba share).
- I tried with file permissions set to 777.

This link suggests it may be an issue related to permissions:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/CDF-Add-NiFi-CA-Service-Service-to-Cluster/m-p/268975/highlight/true

But that does not work for me.

EDIT: I have pasted the XML file contents here:
https://pastebin.com/Q0WE9Y9S

EDIT: I have configured the SAXParserFactory so it does not load external DTD's:

```
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
    factory.setValidating(false);
    factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
    factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

Comment: I suspect your xml file references some other files somewhere that cannot be found. Hard to tell without knowing anything about your xml file.

Comment: So the XML has `<!DOCTYPE preferences SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/preferences.dtd">` meaning an XML parser is trying to read `http://java.sun.com/dtd/preferences.dtd`. How reliable is that? With similar references to e.g. W3C XHTML DTDs people are usually advised to use a catalogue referencing a local copy to the DTDs as the public server might be stalling to cope with too many requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue, it was due to another bug in my own code.
So it had nothing to do with the SAXParser. Thanks for all the help!